# How to convert uintptr to struct and call its functions?

Tags: go, ffi, steam

## Goal

I set myself the goal of rewriting [SteamAchievementManager](https://github.com/gibbed/SteamAchievementManager) from `C#` to `Go`.

## Why?

It might be useful for me and my team first, but it's an open source project, so it might be useful for someone else.

## Problem

The code implements wrappers, and [SAM.API/NativeWrapper.cs](https://github.com/gibbed/SteamAchievementManager/blob/master/SAM.API/NativeWrapper.cs) contains `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` and `Marshal.PtrToStructure` functions that don't exist for Go. Actually, this is our problem.

## Details

1. The following code calls the `CreateInterface` function from `steamclient64.dll` and returns the result (r2 is the result needed to convert it to a structure)

```
func (c *Client) CreateInterface(version string) (r1, r2 uint64, err error) {
    if r1, r2, err = c.Module.Call(
        createInterface,
        uint64(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&version))),
    ); err != nil {
        return
    }
    return
}
```

2. The CreateInterface function is used to get the `SteamClient009` interface from `steamclient64.dll`

```
func GetSteamClient(c *client.Client, name string) (iSteamClient uintptr) {
    if _, steamClient, err := c.CreateInterface(name); !kernel.IsErr(err) {
        if iSteamClient = uintptr(steamClient); iSteamClient == 0 {
            panic(kernel.ErrZeroReturn)
        }
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    c, err := client.New()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _client := GetSteamClient(c, "SteamClient009")
    _ = *(*interfaces.ISteamClient009)(unsafe.Pointer(&_client)) // Attempt to convert to struct
       
    // TODO: Call ISteamClient009 structure functions
}
```

3. `ISteamClient009` from the `interfaces` package

```
type ISteamClient009 struct {
    CreateSteamPipe,
    ReleaseSteamPipe,
    ConnectToGlobalUser,
    CreateLocalUser,
    ReleaseUser,
    GetISteamUser,
    GetISteamGameServer,
    SetLocalIPBinding,
    GetISteamFriends,
    GetISteamUtils,
    GetISteamMatchmaking,
    GetISteamMasterServerUpdater,
    GetISteamMatchmakingServers,
    GetISteamGenericInterface,
    GetISteamUserStats,
    GetISteamGameServerStats,
    GetISteamApps,
    GetISteamNetworking,
    GetISteamRemoteStorage,
    RunFrame,
    GetIPCCallCount,
    SetWarningMessageHook uintptr
}
```

4. Source code: [aivaki/go-SteamAchievementManager](https://github.com/aivaki/go-SteamAchievementManager)

I tried my best to convert uintptr to a function using the `unsafe`, `reflect`, `syscall` packages, but every time I got a runtime error.

If you're here to help, remember that `Steam` must be installed and running for this code to work correctly.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to convert a `uintptr` to a struct, especially one which is not the same size as a `uintptr`. That that `uintptr` is a C pointer to the struct, it should be kept as a pointer to a struct.

Comment: Sorry if this is wrong. It's just that in C# these variables are of type `IntPtr`, and I don't know that language very well.

Comment: If the C API returns a `uintptr` immediately convert that to a pointer of the correct type. There's no reason to keep converting back and forth from between `uintptr` to `uint64` which have different meanings.

Comment: I'm with JimB on `int64`: do not use that. An `uintptr` is a special type to represent "platform-sized integers containing pointers which are not tracked by the Go's GC". You probably want something like [this](https://go.dev/play/p/iA_xoaXVnMd).

Comment: While we're at it, note carefully that `uintptr`s do not count as live references. So when you assign a Go-managed pointer (even `unsafe.Pointer`) to a variable of type `uintptr`, that variable is not considered as pointing at the memory chunk pointed at by the original value, and the existence of that variable will not prevent the GC from collecting that memory chunk.

Comment: Thanks to all. I will stop using `uint64`. But the `CreateInterface` function will only be able to return a value of type `uintptr` because it ends up calling `syscall.SyscallN` to return a value. I remind you that this value is the result of calling the `CreateInterface` function from the DLL.

Comment: This function returns an interface containing functions. If you look at the `SAM.API` code, you will notice that this is implemented using wrappers, for example:
https://gist.github.com/aivaki/c7810a728aa7b52334977c8272f47ff0

Comment: I think it's only possible with functions `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` and `Marshal.PtrToStructure`. Is it even possible to do this in Go? If not, then I'll just build the DLL using SAM.API... And use its exported functions in Go.

Comment: Oh, well, I admit I did not follow the links and only looked at your code (I guess, JimB's analysis was like mine). Peering deeper, I think you might have a problem with your approach: the C# interop you're using as a base appears to use the Steam SDK's DLL(s) as exporting _C++ symbols,_ and all that talk about "interfaces" apparently means C++ vtables which have nothing at all to do with Go's interfaces. This also explains usage of things like `CallingConvention.ThisCall` in the P/Invoke code. …

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254383/discussion-between-kostix-and-aiv-aki).